# Array[Struct] vs Array[Class] garbage collection in .Net / C#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, heap-memory, stack-memory

Scenario A:

```
var intArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 1234567890).ToArray();
```

Scenario B:

```
class myIntClass{ public int myInt { get; set; } }

var arrayOfClasses = Enumerable.Range(1, 1234567890)
.Select(i => new myIntClass() { myInt = i });
```

What's going to be the difference in heap and total memory if I have an array of ints compared to an array of classes when these variables go out of scope and are garbage collected?

It sounds like a silly question, I would assume the array of primitives would be the clear choice.

However... I'm working with some very large arrays and collections of primitive types.
This application is intended to run "forever" but memory usage increases over time and I'm not able to figure out why. I've done some analysis with VS Diagnostic Tools and the CLR Profiler.

According to VS Diagnostic Tools Memory Usage statistics, the heap does not grow at the same rate as the total memory usage figure that I see in Task Manager.

This is the experiment that prompted this question: One part of the application was using large arrays of structs (each struct had two primitive fields). I changed that struct to a class and the result was that the heap size did not grow as quickly over time. It appears that the change improved heap garbage collection as well as total memory usage.

My understanding is that an array is stored on the heap, even if it is an array of primitives. I don't understand then why changing the array contents from a struct to a class would affect heap garbage collection.

When I have a large array of primitives is any stack memory being used? If I created a class with one primitive field and stored an array of that class, instead of an array of primitives, could I reasonably expect the same memory usage improvements that I saw when I changed my struct to a class?

Comment: Sorry, my original title was silly. I've edited the title and some of the post to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Does the app have any unmanaged memoy in COM objects, PInvoke or unsafe code?

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - No, COM objects or PInvoke are not involved. I've written some of the code so no guarantees on safety. :) From what I can tell, from the CLR Profiler, arrays of primitives are taking up the memory. I've edited my question some to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: If you don't have any of those things why are you using structs then? out of curiosity. Also I think your issue could be due to heap fragmentation. try a `sizeof(YourStruct)` and compare that to `sizeof(YourClass)` the array will at least take up N * size memory. If the struct is using two larger primitives and the arrays are very large and being resized/initialized frequently you could run in to memory fragmentation issues.

Comment: [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) by Eric Lippert might help clear things up a bit.

Comment: Also read about “large objects heap” which is likely where differences in your numbers come from

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov +1.  The difference in behavior between an array of structs and an array of classes is that an array of structs is one large memory allocation, likely on the Large Object Heap.  And an array of classes is essentially an array of pointers, and the individual objects are allocated seperately.